# Existence of neighborhood inclusion for 4-chordal graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $N(v)$ be the (open) neighbourhood set of a vertex $v$, and let $N[v]$ be the closed neighbourhood set of $v$.

A graph $G$ is called *4-chordal* if $G$ has no induced cycle with five or more vertices.

**Question:** Does every 4-chordal graph $G$ have two vertices $x$ and $y$ such that
$N(x)$ is a subset of $N(y)$ or $N[x]$ is a subset of $N[y]$?

I think the answer is *yes*, but didn't find a proof so far.

The answer is *yes* for chordal graphs due to simplicial vertices.

But for 4-chordal graphs, I did not see any result in this direction.
There are generalizations of simplicial vertices of $k$-chordal graphs due to Krithika, Mathew, Narayanaswamy and Sadagopan (2013) and Chavatal, Rusu and Sritharan (2002),
but these notions of simplicial vertices do not answer the question as far as I see ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is **no.**  A counterexample is the [triangular prism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_prism) graph.  Up to symmetry, there is a unique 5-cycle and a unique 6-cycle in the triangular prism and both these cycles have chords.  Hence the triangular prism is 4-chordal.  On the other hand, it is also easy to see that no (closed) neighbourhood is contained in any other (closed) neighbourhood.

Comment: I think you mean "Up to symmetry" rather than "By symmetry".

Comment: Thank you very much for your counterexample. It saves quite a lot of time for me...